# Input from txt file doesn't match when it is read/passed second time (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11

So I am fairly new to coding and c++. So...sorry if this is something very obvious to some of you:

I am having a hard time getting this code to read the input stored in txt file for a second time. It works for the first time.

```
void readcode(ifstream& infile, int list[], int& length, bool& lenCodeOk)
{
    int count;
    lenCodeOk = true;

    infile >> length; //get the length of the secret code
    cout << "Length1 is "<<length<<endl;


    if (length > MAX_CODE_SIZE)
    {
            lenCodeOk = false;
            return;
    }
            //Get the secret code.

    for (count = 0; count < length; count++)
    {
            infile >> list[count];
    }

    cout<<" Code recorded is: ";
    for (count = 0; count < length; count++)
    {
            cout<<list[count]<<" "<<endl;
    }
}
```

So the first integer in my txt file is the **length** of the sequence of integers. This function does everything it is supposed to. Reads the length correctly also stores everything in an array.

However when I call the below compareCode function after calling the readcode function, it comes out with a completely random/different **length2** (that changes/goes one up everytime I call) and array elements.

```
void compareCode(ifstream& infile, ofstream& outfile, const int list[], int length)
{

    int length2;
    int digit;
    bool codeOk;
    int count;

    codeOk = true;

    infile >> length2;

    cout<<"Length2 is "<<length<<endl;


    if(length != length)
    {
            cout<< "The original code and its copy are not of the same length"<<endl;
            return;
    }


    outfile << "Code Digit    Code Digit Copy"<<endl;
    for (count= 0; count<length; count++)
    {
            infile >> digit;
            outfile<<setw(5)<<list[count]<<setw(17)<<digit;

            if (digit != list[count])
            {
                    outfile << " Code digits are not the same"<<endl;
                    codeOk = false;
            }
            else
            {
                    outfile<<endl;
    }

            if (codeOk)
            {
                    outfile<<"Message transmitted OK."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                    outfile<<"Error in transmission. "<<"Retransmit!!"<<endl;

              }

    }
}
```

It seems like I am missing an important piece of information about passing fstream variables I would really appreciate if someone pointed me towards the right direction.

```
int main()
{

    int codeArray[MAX_CODE_SIZE];//Array to store the secret code
    int codeLength;// Variable to store the length of the code
    int codeLength2;
    bool lengthCodeOk;//Variable to indicate if the legth of the secret code is less than or equal to 250

    ifstream incode;// Declare ifstream variable
    ofstream outcode;//Declare ofstream variable

    char inputFile[51];//Variable to store the name of the input file
    char outputFile[51]; //Variable to store the name of the output file

    cout<<"Enter the input file name: "<<endl;
    cin>> inputFile;//makesure it is one word because ci.>>skips white space
    cout<<endl;

    incode.open(inputFile);
    if(!incode)
    {
            cout<< "Cannot open the input file."<<endl;
            return 1;
    }

    cout<< "Enter the output file name: " ;
    cin>> outputFile;//Same deal, one word so cin>> can read
    cout<<endl;


    outcode.open(outputFile);

    readcode(incode,codeArray,codeLength,lengthCodeOk);
    if  (lengthCodeOk)
    {
            compareCode(incode,outcode,codeArray,codeLength);
    }
    else
    {
            cout<<"Length of the secret code must be <= "<<MAX_CODE_SIZE<<endl;
    }

    incode.close();
    outcode.close();

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: are you trying to read the file twice at the same run?

Comment: @hasan83 yes. Is that something I shouldn't ?

Comment: no its ok. Do you define a new input stream for the 2nd time?

Comment: did you rewind file before reading it again?

Comment: @hasan83 No , I edited my code so you can also se my main function

Comment: @MarekR No I didn't. Looking into it. This is my first time using external files.

Comment: There are obvious mistake in your code like mixing up length and length2.

Answer (score 0):

this should go like this:

```
istream& readcode(istream& infile, std::vector<int>& list)
{
    int length;
    if (infile >> length) {
        list.reserve(length);
        for (int count = 0; count < length; count++)
        {
            int x;
            if (infile >> x)
            {
                list.push_back(x);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return infile;
}

ifstream file("somefile.txt");
if (file.good())
{
    std::vector<int> a, b;
    if (readcode(file, a).good())
    {
        file.seekg(0);
        if (readcode(file, b).good())
        {
            cout << (a!=b? "code reading are different" : "code reading are same") << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "failed read again code" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "failed read code" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You!!! I'll look into your suggestion first thing in the morning. It's 3 AM now, wasn't expecting a response this fast!